# How to map one list to two lists using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

If I have the following classes:

```
public MainModel
{
    public List<ChildModel> Children {get; set;}
}

public ChildModel
{
    public bool IsDifferent {get; set;}
}

public MainDto
{
    public List<ChildDto> Children {get; set;}
    public List<DifferentChildDto> Different {get; set;}
}

public ChildDto
{ }

public DifferentChildDto
{ }
```

Using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), is it possible to split and map the `ChildModel` list into 2 separate lists based on the property?

The end result shoud be that items with `IsDifferent` property set will be in the `Different` list whilst the remaining items are in the `Children` list.

The mapping should also work in reverse, ie. Merge the two DTO lists into the 1 model list.

Comment: Regarding the reverse mapping: Lists are defined as ordered collections, so how do you expect the order of items for the merged list?

Comment: @grek40 Order is unimportant.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MainModel, MainDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Children, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Children.Where(c => !c.IsDifferent)))
    .ForMember(d => d.Different, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Children.Where(c => c.IsDifferent)));

Mapper.CreateMap<ChildModel, ChildDto>();

Mapper.CreateMap<ChildModel, DifferentChildDto>();
```

Reversing this is not as trivial, you might be better off posting that as a separate question

Comment: How is [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx) not trivial? Edit: ok, maybe the different types are a problem

Comment: because the lists won't have the same type (ChildrenDto vs DifferentChildDto)